# My Ubuntu 22.04 keeps giving me SIGSEV error or network issues

Tags: network-manager, freeze

```
Kernel: 5.19.17-051917-generic
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS
Release:    22.04
Codename:   jammy
```

Please help me as I waste too much time and I have a good system with 32 GB RAM and 512 SSD, processor : Ryzen

```
Architecture:            x86_64
  CPU op-mode(s):        32-bit, 64-bit
  Address sizes:         48 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
  Byte Order:            Little Endian
CPU(s):                  12
  On-line CPU(s) list:   0-11
Vendor ID:               AuthenticAMD
  Model name:            AMD Ryzen 5 5600G with Radeon Graphics
    CPU family:          25
    Model:               80
    Thread(s) per core:  2
    Core(s) per socket:  6
    Socket(s):           1
    Stepping:            0
    Frequency boost:     enabled
    CPU max MHz:         4464.0000
    CPU min MHz:         400.0000
    BogoMIPS:            7785.57
```

Answer (score 0):

`SIGSEV`, aka "Segment violation", indicates an Out-of-bounds memory reference (location 0x0000). It might mean you're missing a dynamic library.

Read `man ldd`, and run `ldd` on the failing binaries. Use `dpkg -S libname` to see the packages providing the library.

Look at the network logs with the terminal command: `sudo journalctl -b 0 -u NetworkManager`. Read `man journalctl NetworkManager service`. Also do: `service NetworkManager status` and `service --status-all`.

Comment: Thanks @waltinator for the response.
I am not sure on what libraries or binaries I should be running ldd. I see this SIGSEV error while my chrome crashing, slack, Node server, JVM.. 
This has started happening since last 3 months when kernel got upgraded but then I downgraded and motherboard doesnt have inbuilt NIC so I am using TP Link Archer 1300 with driver : https://github.com/RinCat/RTL88x2BU-Linux-Driver

I tried lots of things with sensors to check the CPU temp. Please help me more on this.